# blackberry 7 at vmplayer

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, vmware-workstation

URL to download  blackberry 7 to install in VMplayer .

I need to test our SenchTouch app in Blackberry 7 . At simulator senchtouch is not working .

Comment: Where can i see accept option

Comment: There is a little checkmark icon next to each answer.  It looks like "V".  Just click that for the answer that solves your problem.  That says "thanks" to the person who helped you, and lets everyone know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no version of BlackBerry OS 7 that will run under VMWare. Your options are the simulator bundled with the JDE and Plugin for Eclipse (also as stand alone downloads for different versions); or an actual device.